# getting numeric chars out of string

Tags: php, string

I'm having a string (phone number) e.g `+1(234)567-89-01` or `+12345678901`. what is the simpliest way to remove non-numeric chars?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want to remove all non-numeric chars? What do you mean by escaping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant *remove*, not *escape*. To do so, you can simply use a regex:

```
$numbers = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $string);
```

`\D` matches all non-numeric characters so by replacing them with the empty string you'll get a string containing nonly numbers.

Answer (score 3):

this will return numbers with "+" at start:

```
$str = "+1(234)567-89-01";

$number = preg_replace('/[^+\d]/', '', $str);

echo $number;
```